# Как скачать базу PostgreSQL в DJANGO

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

Как мне скачать информацию из postgresql в обычный sqlite3 через django admins

Comment: Используйте эту инструкцию, там всё описано  https://sweetcode.io/django-postgresql-migration-from-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вы используете для этого джанго?

Или это у вас подразумевается такой функционал в вашем проекте который перегоняет базу postgresql в sqlite3?

Я вижу только такой способ:

1. Делаете бекап на postgresql
2. скачиваете клиент sqlite3
3. создаете файл базы db.sqlite3
4. с помощью клиента sqlite3 восстанавливаете бекап из postgresql в db.sqlite3
5. PROFIT!!!!!